# validating certificate chains for PayPal IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to integrate [PHP-PayPal-IPN](https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN) (great library btw, you can see the blog post on usage [here](http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html)).

Since security is essential here, I have checked the source code. I found no apparent problems with it, but I would also like to check the PayPal certificate chain that is bundled with the library: https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN/tree/master/cert

How can I check that the certificate chain is correct? (*correct* == "it allows only connections from PayPal and from nowhere else")

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's the point of it.  That SSL just allows you to setup your IPN script on a secure server so that the data is encrypted.  To my knowledge it's not going to block hits to the script that don't come from PayPal's server.

That's where the verified/unverified check comes into play.  If the data comes from anywhere other than PayPal it will fall into the unverified portion of code.  You can choose to handle these however you want.  Completely ignore them, log them as invalid but keep them for your records, send yourself email notifications, etc.

Comment: Andrew, thanks! But I do check that it is verified (as anyone should). However, it is verified against the supplied cert chains, so if they were supplied by a malicious user, the whole solution would be vulnerable... Am I being too paranoid?